# Php checking 2 values in a same table

Tags: php, mysql

How to check if the 2 values are exist for example

```
=============\
idno   || syearid
c23        2
c23        3
```

Like in the image below:

[image]

If the `idno c23` exist and `syearid 2` exist then it will message that this `idno` and `syearuid` exist. But when I save `idno c23` and `syearid 4` then it will be save because it is the same `idno` but not the same `syearid`. How should I do?

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['save'])){
    $stud_id= $_POST['stud_id'];
    $idno = $_POST['idno'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $middlename= $_POST['middlename'];
    $year= $_POST['year'];
    $dept_id = $_POST['dept_id'];
    $progid = $_POST['progid'];
    $user_type = $_POST['user_type'];
    $password= $_POST['password'];
    $syear= $_POST['syearid'];
    $YearNow=Date('Y');

    $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student,school_year where idno = '$idno' AND student.syearid = school_year.syearid AND school_year.from_year like $YearNow")or die(mysql_error());
    $count1 = mysql_num_rows($sql1);

     if ($idno AND $YearNow == $count1 >1 ) {
         echo"idno $idno has already exist with an exact current year $YearNow";

    }
    else{

    // query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO student VALUES ('$stud_id','$idno','$dept_id','$progid','$syear','0','$lastname','$firstname','$middlename','$year','$password','$user_type')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());



    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
    echo "alert('Successfully Added.');\n";
    echo "window.location = 'addusers.php';";
    echo "</script>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: check my updated ans

Comment: There's no need to check first, and it's counter productive to do so. The topic is called concurrency and is widely discussed

Comment: And after you're done with concurrency, see sql injection, the deprecation of PHP's mysql_ API, and the importance of prepared statements.

Comment: is should that 1 per year

Answer (score 1):

You can  make "idno" and "syearid" as composite unique key for your table

`ALTER TABLE student ADD UNIQUE KEY (idno, syearid);`

It will treat combination of idno and syearid as unique entity and database will generate error while inserting duplicate entry.

Comment: my system is like storing data if idno 'c23'  register in 2015 and try to register again in same year it wil then error but if the student idno 'c23' register in 2016 then it can be save

Comment: Yes, It will serve your purpose. After running above mysql query if you try to insert c23 ,2 (idno and syearid) it will generate error (as per your sample data ) that you can trap inside your code, but will allow you to insert c23,4

Comment: I have to check the idno and the syearid

Comment: Actually i have to focused on both values and the important is the syearid because this will be ...

Answer (score 0):

generate an array
 then you would be able to perform the checks in logic,
 for example check for idno id 2.

I hope this is what your trying to ask.

```
if(in_array(2, $idno)){
    // echo id 2 is received
}
```

Comment: it will have an error in_array when i try to save. it will appear that statement